# SparkConf settings not used when running Spark app in cluster mode on YARN

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management, hadoop-yarn, executor

I wrote a Spark application, which sets sets some configuration stuff via `SparkConf` instance, like this:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test App Name");

conf.set("spark.driver.cores", "1");
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "1800m");

conf.set("spark.yarn.am.cores", "1");
conf.set("spark.yarn.am.memory", "1800m");

conf.set("spark.executor.instances", "30");
conf.set("spark.executor.cores", "3");
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "2048m");

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JavaRDD<String> inputRDD = sc.textFile(...);
...
```

When I run this application with the command (`master=yarn` & `deploy-mode=client`)

```
spark-submit --class spark.MyApp --master yarn --deploy-mode client /home/myuser/application.jar
```

everything seems to work fine, the Spark History UI shows correct executor information:
[image]

But when running it with (`master=yarn` & `deploy-mode=cluster`)

my Spark UI shows wrong executor information (~512 MB instead of ~1400 MB):
[image]

Also my App name equals `Test App Name` when running in client mode, but is `spark.MyApp` when running in cluster mode. It seems that however some default settings are taken when running in Cluster mode. What am I doing wrong here? How can I make these settings for the Cluster mode?

I'm using Spark 1.6.2 on a HDP 2.5 cluster, managed by YARN.

Comment: commenting in haste: what are the values in spark.env.sh, do they differ from what you are setting? check this link https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5222

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I think I found out the problem! In short form: There's a difference between running Spark settings in **Standalone** and in **YARN-managed** mode!

---

So when you run Spark applications in the **Standalone mode**, you can focus on the Configuration documentation of Spark, see http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/configuration.html

You can use the following settings for Driver & Executor CPU/RAM (just as explained in the documentation):

- `spark.executor.cores`
- `spark.executor.memory`
- `spark.driver.cores`
- `spark.driver.memory`

---

BUT: When running Spark inside a **YARN-managed Hadoop environment**, you have to be careful with the following settings and consider the following points:

- orientate on the "Spark on YARN" documentation rather then on the Configuration documentation linked above: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/running-on-yarn.html (the properties explained here have a higher priority then the ones explained in the Configuration docu (this seems to describe only the Standalone cluster vs. client mode, not the YARN cluster vs. client mode!!))
- you can't use `SparkConf` to set properties in yarn-cluster mode! Instead use the corresponding `spark-submit` parameters:

  - `--executor-cores 5`
  - `--executor-memory 5g`
  - `--driver-cores 3`
  - `--driver-memory 3g`
- In yarn-client mode you can't use the `spark.driver.cores` and `spark.driver.memory` properties! You have to use the corresponding AM properties in a `SparkConf` instance:

  - `spark.yarn.am.cores`
  - `spark.yarn.am.memory`
  - You can't set these AM properties via `spark-submit` parameters!
- To set executor resources in yarn-client mode you can use

  - `spark.executor.cores` and `spark.executor.memory` in `SparkConf`
  - `--executor-cores` and `executor-memory` parameters in `spark-submit`
  - if you set both, the `SparkConf` settings overwrite the `spark-submit` parameter values!

---

This is the textual form of my notes:

[image]

Hope I can help anybody else with this findings...

Answer (score 3):

Just to add on to D. Müller's answer:

Same issue happened to me and I tried the settings with some different combination. I am running Pypark 2.0.0 on YARN cluster.

I found that driver-memory must be written during spark submit but executor-memory can be written in script (i.e. SparkConf) and the application will still work.

My application will die if driver-memory is less than 2g. The error is:

> ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
>
> ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User application exited with status 143

---

CASE 1: 
driver & executor both written in SparkConf

```
spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("driver_executor_inside")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .config("spark.executor.memory","4g")
    .config("spark.executor.cores","2")
    .config("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead","1024")
    .config("spark.driver.memory","2g")
    .getOrCreate())
```

`spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster myscript.py`

[image: Job finished with Failed status Error message]
[image: Executors summary in Spark UI]

---

CASE 2:
- driver in spark submit
- executor in SparkConf in script

```
spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("executor_inside")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .config("spark.executor.memory","4g")
    .config("spark.executor.cores","2")
    .config("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead","1024")
    .getOrCreate())
```

`spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.driver.memory=2g myscript.py`

The job Finished with succeed status. Executor memory correct.

[image: Executors summary in Spark UI]

---

CASE 3:
- driver in spark submit
- executor not written

```
spark = (SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("executor_not_written")
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .config("spark.executor.cores","2")
    .config("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead","1024")
    .getOrCreate())
```

`spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.driver.memory=2g myscript.py`

[image: Executors summary in Spark UI]

Apparently the executor memory is not set. Meaning CASE 2 actually captured executor memory settings despite writing it inside sparkConf.